# Can the C# OpenSSL Wrapper read a PKCS12 file and extract the SecretKey entries

Tags: c#, openssl, pkcs#12

I have a .p12 file generated by the Java keytool and need to read all of the Secret Key (AES 256) entries from it so that I can use it to encrypt stuff in my C# app.

I have looked at Bouncy Castle and that only seems to handle Asymmetric keys and X509 certificates.

Can the C# OpenSSL wrapper do this?

Comment: After further digging I have found that neither openssl or bouncy castle support the reading of a "SecretBag" OID from the PKCS12 file. The only other way I can see is protecting my Symmetric keys with RSA and putting them in a password protected zip to replicate the functionality of the (portable) Java Key Store, or a X509 certificate with custom OID entries exported as a PFX which can then be consumed by both C# and Java. Anybody got any thoughts on these suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

.p12 contains the X509Certificate incl. (optionally) the private asymmetric key.
As far as I know, there is no Symmectric (AES) Key in there, but only asymmetric keys.

If you want to use it for S/MIME, it uses a random symmetric kes (AES, 3DES, ...) and enrypts this key with the asymmetric key of the user(s) you send the email to and of course your own.
Have a look at MimeKit and/or MailKit for S/MIME.

If you just want to encrypt some stuff:
Just generate a random AES Key (just some random bytes) and put all of your stuff in some kind of container which includes the asymmetrically encrypted AES key. You could use the ApplicationPKCS from MimeKit (imitating S/MIME) or do something on your own. Just make sure, to identify the certificate you have use to encrypt the symmetric key.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you provide an example of reading SecretKeyEntry(s) from the PKCS key store file using the C# MimeKit. I have been trying to bend my head around it but just don't have enough knowledge in this area.

Comment: You don't!

If you have the appropriate Certificate as .p12, import them to the Windows Certificate Store (or the Mono equivalent on other systems) and use WindowsSecureContext to decrypt the Mimemessage.

If you are not using S/MIME, better work with your own kind of container and assume, that the Certificate will be presented somehow.